# Monitoring file system iops with ganglia

Tags: ganglia

I am trying to monitor a linux system using Ganglia. Is it possible to graphs IOPs on the volumes ?

I read about the diskstat and I think it mostly monitors the disks.

My volumes are mostly logical volumes spanning across disks.

Regards,

Comment: Might I suggest that this would be better asked at http://serverfault.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Sure, I will ask the question there. Thanks